# I keep encountering the error " Error: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody"

Tags: indentation

I know there are other errors present but the main one is the bracket that is supposed to close my main method.  It ask me to enter another bracket to close the class body.  I have gone through many times, correctly indenting and entering in brackets to close loops and methods but it just doesn't want to work.  Any ideas?

```
    import java.util.Stack;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RPNApp{


      public static void main (String [] args)
      {
        /* Scanner object which takes user input and splits each element into an array of type String*/
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers and operators for the Reverse Polish Notation calculator.");
        String scanner = scan.nextLine();
        String [ ] userInput = scanner.split(" ");
        Stack<Long> stack = new Stack<Long>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length; i++) {

          if (isNumber()) {

            Long.parseLong(userInput[i]);
            stack.push(Long.parseLong(userInput[i]));
          }
        }
      }






      public static boolean isOperator (String userInput[i]) //userInput is the array.
      {
        for (int i = 0; i<userInput.length; i++) {

          if (!(x.equals("*") || x.equals("+") || x.equals("-") || x.equals("/") || x.equals("%"))) {
            return false;

          }else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }






      public static boolean isNumber (String userInput[i]) 
      {
        for (int i = 0; i<x.length(); i++) {
          char c = x.charAt(i);
          if (!(Character.isDigit(c))) {
            return false;
          }


        } return true;
      }
    }
```

I have made quite a few changes, I knew there were other errors present.  But the error I encountered from not having a correct parameter in my method was the worry. You mentioned there was still something wrong, have I tended to the syntax error you noticed?

### Updated code

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPNApp{


  public static void main (String [] args){   
    /* Scanner object which takes user input and splits each element into an array of type String*/
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers and operators for the Reverse Polish Notation calculator.");
    String scanner = scan.nextLine();
    String [ ] userInput = scanner.split(" ");
    Stack<Long> stack = new Stack<Long>();


    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
      String current = userInput[i];

      if (isNumber(current)) {

        Long.parseLong(userInput[i]);
        stack.push(Long.parseLong(userInput[i]));
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
      }
    }     
  }
  public static boolean isOperator (String x) { //userInput is the array.

      if (!(x.equals("*") || x.equals("+") || x.equals("-") || x.equals("/") || x.equals("%"))) {
        return false;

      }else {
        return true;
      }
    }

  public static boolean isNumber (String x) {

    for (int i = 0; i<x.length(); i++) {
      char c = x.charAt(i);
      if (!(Character.isDigit(c))) {
        return false;
      }

    } return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `i < userInput.length` looks better now. Does it run? If it doesn't, tell us exactly what happens (error messages).
Wait a second: First things First: **Do you have JRE + JDK with a working Java compiler installed**?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin  Yeah pretty sure, I am able to use Dr. Java and can efficiently compile my code(if it is correct).  This code compiled, I just wanted to push numbers onto the stack,  If it is a number.  I just figured out how to do this.

Comment: Hint: "designed primarily for students, providing an intuitive interface" = (most probably) unmaintained trashware written by people who were uninformed enough to think that they were able to compete against Eclipse, NetBeans, Emacs, Vim, Sublime, Ant and Maven. User base consists of few hundred of clueless students who were *forced* to use this trashware, so nobody can help if something goes wrong. I strongly suggest to get rid of it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code certainly has more than just a few issues. But if you have written it entirely in your head without ever compiling it, it's actually pretty good! It shows that you think about the problem in a surprisingly correct way. I don't understand how one can get so many details wrong, but the overall structure right. And some of the syntax errors aren't really your fault: it's absolutely not obvious why it should be `array.length` but `string.length()` but at the same time `arrayList.size()`, it's completely inconsistent mess.

Here, I cleaned it up a bit:

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPNApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Scanner object which takes user input and splits each element into an array of type String*/
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers and operators for the Reverse Polish Notation calculator.");
    String scanner = scan.nextLine();
    String[] userInput = scanner.split(" ");
    Stack<Long> stack = new Stack<Long>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length; i++) {
      if (isNumber(userInput[i])) {
        Long.parseLong(userInput[i]);
        stack.push(Long.parseLong(userInput[i]));
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean isOperator(String userInput) {
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
      char x = userInput.charAt(i);
      if (!(x == '*' || x == '+' || x == '-' || x == '/' || x == '%')) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static boolean isNumber(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char c = s.charAt(i);
      if (!(Character.isDigit(c))) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Few other points to notice:

1. Exists-loops: Check `if true`, `return true` in loop, `return false` in the end.
2. Forall-loops: Check `if false`, `return false` in loop, `return true` in the end.
3. Chars and Strings are not the same. Chars are enclosed in single quotes and compared by `==`.

It's still wrong. Think harder why. And try not to post non-compilable stuff any more.

Comment: @Andrew Tyukin 
Thanks for your pointers Andrey, I realised that the main issue was my parameters for both methods.  I understand checking to see if something is false and returning true in the end.  But why would I want vice versa for Exists loops(I'm assuming exists loops check to see if a certain element exist in an array/string etc etc)? And sorry about posting non-compilable stuff, I was just hoping someone could point out my error.

Comment: I have tended to a lot of the errors in my first post, the new code is under the UPDATED header.  Was wondering if you could possibly give it a quick look?  I changed the parameters and took out the for loop in the isOperator method.

Answer (score 1):

In your function parameters you can't have userInput[i] like that. Get rid of the [i] part and then fix the rest of the other errors.